# Implementation using io.vertx.mutiny in Quarkus does not change the value to be returned

Tags: java, quarkus, vert.x, smallrye

We are building a reactive system by implementing it using io.vertx.mutiny in Quarkus.
At this time, a single value was tested and confirmed to be returned. However, variables that are expected to return multiple records will not finish processing and will eventually be cancelled. How should I deal with this?

I would appreciate it if you could enjoy it if you know the solution.

Import-Block

```
import io.smallrye.mutiny.Multi; import io.smallrye.mutiny.Uni; import io.vertx.mutiny.pgclient.PgPool; import io.vertx.mutiny.sqlclient.Row; import io.vertx.mutiny.sqlclient.RowSet; import io.vertx.mutiny.sqlclient.SqlClient; import io.vertx.mutiny.sqlclient.Tuple;`
```

```
private final PgPool client;
```

Success Method

```
private final String FETCH_BY_ID = "SELECT p.*, c.name as category_name FROM products p INNER JOIN categories c ON p.category_id = c.id WHERE p.id = $1";
 @Override
    public Uni<Product> searchProduct(UUID productId) {
        return this.executeFetchById(productId, this.client);
    }

    private Uni<Product> executeFetchById(UUID productId, SqlClient client) {
        return client
                .preparedQuery(FETCH_BY_ID)
                .execute(Tuple.of(productId))
                .onItem().transform(RowSet::iterator)
                .onItem().transform(iterator -> iterator.hasNext() ? toProduct(iterator.next()) : null)
                .onItem().transform(entity -> ObjectUtils.isNotEmpty(entity) ? productTranslator.toDomain(entity) : null);
    }
```

Failure

```
    @Override
    public Multi<Product> searchProducts(String sortKey, String order, Integer limit, Integer offset) {

        final String query = generateSearchProductsQuery(sortKey, order);

        return client
                .preparedQuery(query)
                .execute(selectTuple(limit, offset))
                .onItem().transformToMulti(rows -> Multi.createFrom().iterable(rows))
                .onItem().transform(this::toProduct)
                .onItem().transform(entity -> ObjectUtils.isNotEmpty(entity) ? productTranslator.toDomain(entity) : null);
    }

    private Tuple selectTuple(Integer limit, Integer offset) {
        return Tuple.wrap(Arrays.asList(
                Objects.isNull(limit) ? 10 : limit,
                Objects.isNull(offset) ? 0 : offset));
    }

    private String generateSearchProductsQuery(String sortKey, String order) {
        String baseQuery = "SELECT p.*, c.name as category_name FROM products p INNER JOIN categories c ON p.category_id = c.id ORDER BY %s %s LIMIT $1 OFFSET $2";
        String finalSortKey = Objects.isNull(sortKey) ? "p.id" : sortKey;
        String finalOrder = Objects.isNull(order) ? "ASC" : order;
        return String.format(baseQuery, finalSortKey, finalOrder);
    }
```

```
return client
                .preparedQuery(query)
                .execute(selectTuple(limit, offset))
                .onItem().transformToMulti(rows -> Multi.createFrom().iterable(rows))
                .onItem().transform(this::toProduct)
                .log("TEST A")
                .onItem().transform(entity -> ObjectUtils.isNotEmpty(entity) ? productTranslator.toDomain(entity) : null);
```

”TEST A”　is displayed, but the process was never completed.

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier if you had a full reproducer project somewhere, and any error log / stack-trace would also help.

That being said I'm seeing something very suspicious:

```java
.onItem().transform(entity -> ObjectUtils.isNotEmpty(entity) ? productTranslator.toDomain(entity) : null)
```

This could insert `null` values in a `Multi` stream, and that is not permitted in the *Reactive Streams* specification that `Multi` implements.
When a `transform` handler returns `null`, then the stream is errored.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out.
As you pointed out, the design that returns Null is certainly not appropriate. .

I will review this again!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to deal with it by doing only OrderBy separately as shown below, but the reason is not clear. Sorry for the inconvenience.

```
@Override
    public Multi<Product> searchProducts(String sortKey, String order, Integer limit, Integer offset) {

        final String query = QueryHelper.setOrderInQuery(ProductCommand.FECTH, order);

        return client
                .preparedQuery(query)
                .execute(selectTuple(sortKey, limit, offset))
                .onItem().transformToMulti(rows -> Multi.createFrom().iterable(rows))
                .onItem().transform(this::toProduct)
                .onItem().transform(entity -> ObjectUtils.isNotEmpty(entity) ? productTranslator.toDomain(entity) : null);
    }

    private Tuple selectTuple(String key, Integer limit, Integer offset) {
        return Tuple.wrap(Arrays.asList(
                Objects.isNull(key) ? " p.id" : key,
                Objects.isNull(limit) ? 10 : limit,
                Objects.isNull(offset) ? 0 : offset));
```